# AST how to deal with empty nodes

Tags: java, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, interpreter

I am building an expression evaluator using Java, JFlex(lexer gen) and Jacc(parser gen). I need to:

- generate the lexer
- generate the parser
- generate the AST
- display the AST graph
- evaluate expression

I was able to create the lexer and the parser and the AST. Now I am trying to make the AST graph using the visitor pattern, but this made a problem with my generated AST evident (so to speak). In my calculator I need to handle parentheses and they create empty nodes in my AST (and that makes my parse tree not an AST I suppose). Here is the relevant part of my grammar:

```
Calc : /* empty */
    | AddExpr                   { ast = new Calc($1); }
    ;

AddExpr : ModExpr
    | AddExpr '+' ModExpr       { $$ = new AddExpr($1, $3, "+"); }
    | AddExpr '-'   ModExpr     { $$ = new AddExpr($1, $3, "-"); }
    ;

ModExpr : IntDivExpr
    | ModExpr MOD IntDivExpr    { $$ = new ModExpr($1, $3); }
    ;

IntDivExpr : MultExpr
    | IntDivExpr DIV MultExpr   { $$ = new IntDivExpr($1, $3); }
    ;

MultExpr : UnaryExpr
    | MultExpr '*' UnaryExpr    { $$ = new MultExpr($1, $3, "*"); }
    | MultExpr '/' UnaryExpr    { $$ = new MultExpr($1, $3, "/"); }
    ;

UnaryExpr : ExpExpr
    | '-' UnaryExpr             { $$ = new UnaryExpr($2, "-"); }
    | '+' UnaryExpr             { $$ = new UnaryExpr($2, "+"); }
    ;

ExpExpr : Value                 
    | ExpExpr '^' Value         { $$ = new ExpExpr($1, $3); }
    ;

Value : DoubleLiteral           
    | '(' AddExpr ')'           { $$ = new Value($2); }
    ;

DoubleLiteral : DOUBLE          { $$ = $1; }
    ;
```

Here is an example expression:

```
1*(2+3)/(4-5)*((((6))))
```

and the resulting image:

[image]

This leaves me with `Value` nodes for each pair of parentheses. I have a few ideas on how to handle this, but I am not sure how to proceed:

- Try to handle this in my grammar (not sure how as I am not allowed to use precedence directives)
- Handle this in my evaluator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want `Value` nodes, then just replace `{ $$ = new Value($2); }` with `{ $$ = $2; }`.